# Creating a virtualenv - tutorials don't work for me :(?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have looked at a number of tutorials for Windows on creating a virtual environment and have hit a brick wall. I ran

```
  virtualenv --no-site-packages <foldername>
```

which returns
New python executable in launch\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

I am then told to run:

```
source <foldername>/bin/activate
```

but no bin directory has been created so it can't find the file.

Where have I gone wrong since clearly I need the bin directory to run a file from within it!

thanks

Comment: `activate` will also be in `/Scripts`

Comment: great thanks - just tried without source and it works :) i.e. just <foldername>/Scripts/activate - easy when you know how :)